# array join() method without a separator

Tags: javascript

```
var arr= ['g','o','o','d'];
var arr2 = arr.join();
```

Arr2 will be "g,o,o,d". I would like to get "good". I know there are a million other ways to achieve this but was curious if there was a way with join.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Sure - just pass an empty string:

```
var arr2 = arr.join('');
```