# using .join method to convert array to string without commas

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [array join() method without a separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125779/array-join-method-with-a-separator)

I'm using `.join()` to convert my array to a string so I can output it in a text box as the user selects numbers in a calculator, I'm not entirely sure how I can remove the commas that are also being output in the list however. Can someone advise how this can be achieved or if there is a different approach I should be using?

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var total = 0;
    var arr = [];

    //Testing
    $('#calculator').children('.num').on('click', function(e) {
        var clickedNumber = $(this).data('id');
        arr.push(clickedNumber);
        console.log(arr.join());
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});​
```

JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CVr25/

Comment: `.join` is a native array method, it's not part of jQuery.

Comment: @FelixKling: Shouldn't it rather be named "…without a separator"? :-)

Comment: @Bergi: Probably :) You can edit it ;)

Answer (score 357, accepted):

Simply like that:

```
arr.join("")
```

Answer (score 46):

You can specify an empty string as an argument to join, if no argument is specified a comma is used.

```
 arr.join('');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/CVr25/1/

Answer (score 39):

The [`.join()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) has a parameter for the separator string. If you want it to be empty instead of the default comma, use

```
arr.join("");
```

Answer (score 24):

All you need to do is :

```
arr.join('');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/CVr25/4/)