# How to remove the commas in arrays javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

**I would like to know whether I can remove the commas when printing out the output.**

This is my code:

```
var allRows = [];
var numberOfRows = 10;

var number = 0;
while (number < numberOfRows) {
  allRows[allRows.length] = "O";
  number++;
}

var numberOfRowsNumber = 0;

while (numberOfRowsNumber < numberOfRows) {
  var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
  var txt = document.createTextNode(allRows);
  paragraph.appendChild(txt);
  var element = document.getElementById("output");
  element.appendChild(paragraph);
  numberOfRowsNumber++;
}
```

This is the output of the above code:

[image]

My expected output would be the following:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: [`var txt = document.createTextNode(allRows.join(''))`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using .join method to convert array to string without commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132178/using-join-method-to-convert-array-to-string-without-commas)

Comment: Yes also! Thanks so much y'all!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A cleaner approach:

```js
var numberOfRows = 10;
(allRows = []).length = numberOfRows; 
allRows.fill("O");

var outputElement = document.getElementById("output");
allRows.forEach(val => {
  outputElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<p>' + allRows.join('') + '</p>');
});
```

```html
<div id="output" />
```