# Javascript, is there a way to write an array as a single text string without commas or gaps?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [array join() method without a separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125779/array-join-method-without-a-separator)

I'm trying to code a simple array that will then be displayed as a single, continuous line of text with no comma's gaps or separations of any kind. For example, if the array was about fruit, and the fruit involved were apples[0] and bananas[1], it would be displayed as applesbananas.

I am also using socket io and tried the array.join command, but that came up as a 'native expression' in the cmd, which I wasn't sure what to do with.

This is the code I have so far:

```
var A = 0
var B = 0
var master = new Array();

io.sockets.on("connection", function (socket) {


    socket.on("message", function (data) {

        var new_data = data.split(',');

        if (new_data == 'A') {
            master.push(new_data)
            console.log(A);
        }
        else if (new_data == 'B') {
            master.push(new_data)
            console.log(B);
        }
        var final = (master.join);
            console.log(final);
            socket.emit("message", 'master,' + final);
            socket.broadcast.emit("message", 'master,' + final);
```

Right now, this .join expression is being displayed as a native expression in the cmd. Is there any way to join the array elements in a way the cmd or socket io will understand?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `.join` is a method, you have to call it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join.

Comment: how about `master.join(",")` ?

Answer (score 2):

You're seeing that error because you're missing parenthesis after your call to `.join`.

You can join an array with no spaces using `.join('')`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var final = master.join("");
```